# Как сделать такие соц. иконки?

Tags: html, css

Я пытаюсь сделать через шрифт. Не получается четко поставить иконку в центр рамки. Очень хочу узнать как бы вы это сделали.

[image: Иконки]

Comment: Я и делаю через шрифтовые иконки

Comment: Именно через него

Comment: Версии 4 или 5?

Comment: -------  v 4.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Подобный эффект делается через вставку исходного кода `SVG` изображения в код документа или созданием [SVG спрайта](http://nicothin.pro/page/svg-sprites). После чего вы получите доступ к изменению цвета изображения через `CSS`:

```
svg.icon{
    fill: #fff;
}
svg.icon:hover{
    fill: #0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример. Использовано несколько строчек собственного `css` кода и `font awesome`.

```css
.fa-circle-thin {
  color: #51e265;
}

.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle-thin {
  color: #51e265;
}

.fa-circle {
  color: transparent;
}

.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle {
  color: #51e265;
}

.fa-stack:hover .fa-inverse {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.fa-inverse {
  color: #51e265 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы обводка была тоньше?

Comment: @Topik, поменяй класс у FontAwesome допустим на `fa-facebook`, затем сделай `padding` или `width` & `height` для иконки, а после добавь `border` и добавь скругление `border-radius`

Comment: @entithat, элементарные вопросы, вот бы побольше таких вопросов на тему `SVG`:)))

Comment: @entithat, зависит от приоритетов и предпочтений. Лично я больше склоняюсь к дизайну, редко затрагиваю иное:)

Answer (score 1):

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/) нормально центрирует иконки сам.

Пример для **v4.7.0**

```css
i{
color:#67BF95;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Пример страницы</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>

<body>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>

  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Я скачивал две иконки awesome с сайта fontello.com

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, задать line-height такой же как и высота блока

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.social {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #67bf95;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.facebook {
  border: 5px solid #67bf95;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.fa-pencil{
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #67bf95;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="social pencil">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</div>
<div class="social facebook">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: @entithat тогда твой вариант в самый раз